# Using 24 hour time in bootstrap timepicker

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

Hi im using http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/ on bootstrap, specifically example number 4.

I added this property to take away the PM thing and be able to use 24 system on the widget itself:

> format: 'hh:mm',

But lets say I pick 16:00 on the widget it shows up at 04:00 on the input itself as opposed to 16:00.

I could not find anything in the documentation about this so if anyone knows a fix for this it would be really appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: You might be able to find some info in the comments [here](https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/issues/42)

Comment: Yes i set the language to en, didnt help. and what do you mean I might be able to find info in the comments?

Comment: I was having this problem for the longest time and then found it was my initial inout string that wasn't getting put into 24 hour format. Once I fixed that everything started working. :)

Comment: HH:mm for 24 hour time

hh:mm for 12 hour time.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/21847556

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**EDIT:**  There are much better answers on this thread than this one.  I was just getting the hang of JavaScript at the time I answered.  Specifically, see [these](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25874594/2344773) [two](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22673819/2344773).

If you search within the development version of that script, there's a function called `use24hours` that looks for a value of either true or false.

Adding `use24hours:true` might do the job for you. Like so:

```
$(function () {
    $('#datetimepicker5').datetimepicker({
        use24hours: true
    });
});
```

Comment: Whoops, that '-' was supposed to be an '='.  Also, I haven't tested this yet.  I submitted this as an answer only to show that bit of code.  If you haven't figured it out by tonight, I'll write-up a jsfiddle to see if we can get it working.  This looks like a cool script to use with bootstrap :)

Comment: are you sure its not supposed to be ":"?

Comment: option use24hours is not recognized!

Comment: Note: as of at least 27/07/2015 the use24hours option has been removed. Changing the format to HH:mm will result in a 24 hour clock.

Answer (score 49):

Use capitals letter for hours HH = 24 hour format an hh = 12 hour format

```js
$('#fecha').datetimepicker({
   format : 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm'
});
```

Answer (score 26):

```
$('.time-picker').timepicker({
            showMeridian: false     
        });
```

This will work.

Comment: Perfect. //Timepicker
    $(".timepicker").timepicker({
      showInputs: false,
      showMeridian: false
    });

Answer (score 26):

This works for me:

```
$(function () {
    $('#datetimepicker5').datetimepicker({
        use24hours: true,
        format: 'HH:mm'
    });
});
```

**Important:** It only worked at the point I used uppercase "H" as time format.

Comment: Note: as of at least 27/07/2015 the `use24hours` option has been removed. Changing the format to `HH:mm` will result in a 24 hour clock.

Comment: If you also need the month/day/year, use this:

.datetimepicker({ 
        format: 'mm/DD/YYYY HH:mm'
    });

Answer (score 14):

```
"YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss" => 24 hours format;

"YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss" => 12 hours format;
```

the difference is letter 'H'

Comment: Great answer datetime format works for `datetimepicker` and `daterangepicker`

Answer (score 13):

To pick only time with 24 hr time format, use

```
$('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
            format: 'HH:mm'
 });
```

If you want to pick 24 hr time format with date also, use

```
$('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
         format: 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm'
 });
```

Example :

```js
$(function() {
  $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
            format: 'HH:mm'
  });
  
  $('#datetimepicker2').datetimepicker({
            format: 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm'
  });
  $('#datetimepicker3').datetimepicker({
      format: 'hh:mm A',
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.15.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.7.14/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.7.14/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class='col-sm-6'>
      <div class="form-group">
        <span>Select 24 hour time format</span>
        <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
          <input type='text' class="form-control" />
          <span class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
          </span>
        </div>
        <br/>
        <span>Select time with Date</span>
        <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker2'>
          <input type='text' class="form-control" />
          <span class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
          </span>
        </div>
        <br/>
        <span>Select 12 hour time format</span>
        <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker3'>
          <input type='text' class="form-control" />
          <span class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[For more info](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/)

Answer (score 10):

It looks like you have to set the option for the format with data-date-*. This example works for me with 24h support.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group date timepicker"
        data-date-format="HH:mm"
        data-date-useseconds="false"
        data-date-pickDate="false">

        <input type="text" name="" />
        <div class="input-group-addon">
            <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

And this works for me:

```
$(function () {
    $('#datetimepicker5').datetimepicker({
        format: 'HH:mm'
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

if you are using bootstrap time picker.
use showMeridian property to make the time picker 24 hours format.

```
$('.time-picker').timepicker({
            showMeridian: false     
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

This will surely help on bootstrap timepicker

```
format :"DD:MM:YYYY HH:mm"
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have to set the option for the format with data-date-*. This example works for me with 24h support.

Answer (score 0):

The below code is correct answer for me.

```
 $('#datetimepicker6').datetimepicker({
                    format : 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm'
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>    
    $(function () {

        /* setting time */
        $("#timepicker").datetimepicker({
            format : "HH:mm:ss"
        });

    }    
</script>
```

[Example bootstrap datetimepicker eonasdan](https://codepen.io/antelove/pen/EqoLbz)

Answer (score -1):

```
<input type="text" name="time" data-provide="timepicker"  id="time" class="form-control" placeholder="Start Time" value="" />


$('#time').timepicker({
        timeFormat: 'H:i',
        'scrollDefaultNow'      : 'true',
        'closeOnWindowScroll'   : 'true',
        'showDuration'          : false,
        'ignoreReadonly'        : true,

})
```

work for me.

Answer (score -2):

```
//Timepicker
$(".timepicker").timepicker({
  showInputs: false,
  showMeridian: false //24hr mode 
});
```