# DateTimePicker time picker in 24 hour but displaying in 12hr?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datetimepicker

I'm using the bootstrap ready date time picker from http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/ and it's working nicely but for one issue. I have a picker setup just from time as so:

```
$(function () {
    $('#startTime, #endTime').datetimepicker({
        format: 'hh:mm',
        pickDate: false,
        pickSeconds: false,
        pick12HourFormat: false            
    });
});
```

This sets the picker to 24 hour so I can select 19:00 as a time. But when I choose this time it displays as 07:00 in the input box. Here is the setup displaying the picker:

```
    <div class="input-group date timePicker" id="endTime">
        <input type='text' class="form-control" readonly="true"
            id="endTimeContent" /> <span class="input-group-addon"><span
            class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span> </span>
    </div>
```

Is there a specific data-format I can use for 24 hour in the input box?

Comment: remove this pick12HourFormat and check

Answer (score 37):

Because the picker script is using [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) to parse the format string, you can read the docs there for proper format strings.

But for 24Hr time, use `HH` instead of `hh` in the format.

```
$(function () {
    $('#startTime, #endTime').datetimepicker({
        format: 'HH:mm',
        pickDate: false,
        pickSeconds: false,
        pick12HourFormat: false            
    });
});
```

Answer (score 18):

To show the correct 24H format, for example, only put

```
$(function () {
    $('#date').datetimepicker({
         format: 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm',
    });

});
```

Answer (score 15):

```
$(function () {
    $('#startTime, #endTimeContent').datetimepicker({
        format: 'HH:mm',
        pickDate: false,
        pickSeconds: false,
        pick12HourFormat: false            
    });
});
```

your selector seems to be wrong,please check it

Comment: Ah so simple, I just assumed that part was all working as I was seeing the correct 24 format in the time picker.

Answer (score 7):

Just this!

```
$(function () {
    $('#date').datetimepicker({
         format: 'H:m',
    });

});
```

**i use v4 and work well!!**

Answer (score 6):

I don't understand why the other friends tell you use `HH`, But after I test so many time, The correct 24 hour format is :

> hh

.

I see it from : http://www.malot.fr/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

I don't know why they don't use the common type `HH` for 24 hour.....

I hope anyone could tell me if I'm wrong.....

Comment: This the right and acceptable answer

Answer (score 3):

With seconds!

```
$('.Timestamp').datetimepicker({
    format: 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss'
});
```

To skip future dates:

```
$(function () {
    var date = new Date();
    var currentMonth = date.getMonth();
    var currentDate = date.getDate();
    var currentYear = date.getFullYear();
    $('#datetimepicker,#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
        pickTime: false,
        format: "DD-MM-YYYY",  
        maxDate: new Date(currentYear, currentMonth, currentDate + 1)
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Meridian pertains to AM/PM, by setting it to false you're indicating you don't want AM/PM, therefore you want 24-hour clock implicitly.

```
$('#timepicker1').timepicker({showMeridian:false});
```

Comment: Please describe what that fix is. StackOverflow doesn't like code-only answers because it makes it harder for people to figure out the intention and if it's even worth studying the code at all. If you say what it does and how it solves the problem, people can figure out if they want to invest time in your answer. I understand it seems obvious to you and to me what this one line of code does, but it won't for everyone who may be looking over the answers.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's been quite some time since the question was asked. However, if it helps anyone this worked for me.

```
 $(function() {
    $('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
        format: 'MM-DD-YYYY HH:mm '
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the parameters "**use24hours**" and "**language**" to do this, as follows:

```js
$(function () {
    $('.datetime').datetimepicker({
        language: 'pt-br',
        use24hours: true,
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

'DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm A'     =>  12 hours                                   'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm A'     =>  24 hours

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

this will display current ate & time. Working on my side perfectly

```
$("#datePicker").datetimepicker({
    format: 'DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm A',
    defaultDate: new Date(),
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Perfectly worked for me

```
jQuery('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
    use24hours: true,   
    format: "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm ",
    defaultDate: new Date(),
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The catch is that *hh* is for format 12 hours and *HH* is for 24 hours.

**24 hour format**

```
$(function () {
    $('#customElement').datetimepicker({
        format: 'HH:mm',           
    });
});
```

**12 hour format**

```
$(function () {
    $('#customElement').datetimepicker({
        format: 'hh:mm',           
    });
});
```

Comment: How can we remove repetition of 1 to 12 2 times I am using telerik blazor ?
https://docs.telerik.com/blazor-ui/components/timepicker/overview?_ga=2.249302599.1961766430.1643988352-713448822.1634827065

Comment: This comment is related to DateTimePicker library http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/ . That one that you ask is some other library.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, you need to use 'hh:mm':

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('body').on('click', '.form_datetime', function() {
    $(this).datetimepicker({
      format: "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm",
      showMeridian: true,
      autoclose: true,
      todayBtn: true,
      pick12HourFormat: false   
    });

    $(this).trigger('focus');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.timepicker').datetimepicker({
  format: "HH:mm:ss",
});
```

CAPITAL HH is for 24 hour and SMALL hh is for 12 hour inputs