# How to i create a HTML input field that accepts time in 24Hrs?

Tags: jquery, html, css

i need to create an input field that accepts time in 24hhrs, i have tried using

```
<input type="time" name="t1" />
```

but this accepts the time in 12hrs. Is there a way to solve my issue? The 12HRS time input was nicely formatted and it display time in HH:MM i also need the same in my 24Hrs at least the HH:MM part

Comment: What is wrong with it? I can choose from 00 to 23 hours in your input.

Comment: Time fields are 24h format by default...?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan are you sure, 'cus on chrome browser it shows AM/PM

Comment: @FeddrickMoria What version of Chrome are you using? I can set values from 00 to 23 (full 24 hours clock).

Comment: I'm using Chrome 50 and get no AM/PM: http://i.imgur.com/jt1qHEs.png

Comment: _"i also need the same in my 24Hrs"_ Not certain what you mean? You should be able to set `AM` or `PM` at rightmost control?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Interesting. Can you create a jsfiddle. At chrome 49 now though fairly certain chromium 50 renders `AM`, `PM` control. There appears to be a space at rightmost portion of `input` at image where `AM` or `PM` could be selected? Will not be able to try until later

Comment: Version 50.0.2661.102 m, and I have an AM/PM input, not a 24h input. http://jsfiddle.net/Yp3b3/

Comment: I just copied the OPs HTML in to a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/oojwupd8/

Comment: @coyotte508 I have the same version, which leads me to believe it's a locale based preference which Chrome is using.

Comment: Give a sec, will try at chromium 50

Comment: It's related to how your time is set in your OS. Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13523060/html5-time-inputs-shows-12-hours) out.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21847443/datetimepicker-time-picker-in-24-hour-but-displaying-in-12hr

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan `AM` , `PM` control is rendered at chromium 50.0.2654.0

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Are you trying on a mobile device?

Comment: @mplungjan Not certain about relevance of link to "DateTimePicker time picker in 24 hour but displaying in 12hr?" as to current Question?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Note, if `AM`, `PM` option is not rendered by default, the contol could be built using `shadowDOM`, including any other specific controls required; as `shadowDOM` is how the control is implemented at the `host` `input` element, at chrome / chromium; you can view this by inpecting the `input` element

Comment: It is relevant to use a jQuery time picker when html5 fails to provide a 24hour time picker when the locale gives am pm back

Comment: @mplungjan That does not solve how to adjust default `<input type="time">` element to render `AM`, `PM`; or address why similar versions of chrome appear to render controls differently. Yes, you could use a jQuery plugin. You could also built the entire control from scratch, and include any controls required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way time is presented 12hr-24hr has to do with your OS settings, meaning that if you have set in your OS the time to be displayed in 12hr format so it will in your browser. (do mind time input is not supported in firefox so basically a text input with a pattern might be a good idea)

if you want you may define min and max values

```
  <input type="time" min="00:00:00" max="23:59:59" name="usr_time">
```

based on the documentation https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.time.html

Comment: _"The way time is presented 12hr-24hr is due to which browser you use"_ That is fairly broad. You could create your own custom build of a browser. Which browsers render which controls?

Comment: The actual rendering of the `input` controls could be adjusted by altering the `shadowDOM` at the `host` `input` element

Comment: @guest271314 yes it should write "input with type time is not supported by all browsers"