# how to set am/pm format in jquery using datetimepicker

Tags: jquery

this is my jquery code.eventdatpicker is display date only,but occasionStartTime and occasionEndTime it display 24 hours format only how to change this format to am/pm format?

```
$(function() {
    $('#occasionStartTime').datetimepicker({
        datepicker : false,
        format : 'H:i'
    });
    $('#occasionEndTime').datetimepicker({
        datepicker : false,
        format : 'H:i'

    });
    $('#eventDatePicker').datetimepicker({
        timepicker : false,
        format : 'd.m.Y'
    });
});
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try

```
$('#occasionStartTime').datetimepicker({
    datepicker : false,
    ampm: true, // FOR AM/PM FORMAT
    format : 'g:i A'
});
```

Comment: By using this code how to show PM or AM?ur code only shows folllowing output **20-09-2016 03:01:57** @Jef

Comment: validateOnBlur: false //add this to prevent PM to change AM on moving pointer off from input

Answer (score 11):

```
$('#StartDate').datetimepicker(
                {
                    format: 'DD MMM YYYY hh:mm A'

                });
```

where startDate is a divId

```
    <div class="input-group date form_datetime" id="StartDate">
         <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="From" name="StartDate" id="txtStartDate" required /> 
<span class="input-group-addon">
<span class="glyphicon-calendar glyphicon"></span></span>
 </div>
```

This will give you format like: 25 Mar 2016 01:08 PM

Comment: add some description too.

Comment: works great, works directly with mvc default data structure

Answer (score 4):

```
$('#occasionStartTime').datetimepicker({
        format: 'Y/m/d A g:i',
        formatTime: 'A g:i',
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

MVC Default Dateformat using Bootstrap Datepicker3 - very useful for beginers

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
<script src="~/Content/datepicker/moment.js"></script>
<link href="~/Content/datepicker/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/Content/datepicker/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js"></script>
```

```
    $(function () {
        $('.datetime').datetimepicker({
            format: 'DD-M-YYYY hh:mm A'
        });

    });

</script>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use this plugin to unobtrusively add a datetimepicker, datepicker or timepicker dropdown to your forms. It's easy to customize options.

You can download Plugin: [Download](https://github.com/xdan/datetimepicker/archive/master.zip)

add js and css to head tag:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./js/jquery.datetimepicker.css" />
<script src="./js/jquery.datetimepicker.js"></script>
```

add this code to you want show:

```
$(function () {
    $('#video_schedule').datetimepicker({
        step:5,
        minDate:0,
        formatTime:'H:i'
    });
});
```

Comment: In function code, the `formatTime`  should be `'g:i A'`. That was the expected answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you've only got a time field instead of a datetime field - you can set AM/PM format using

```
 $("#yourTimeField").timepicker({
        showPeriod: true
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Set your datatimepicker format value as `format: 'hh:mm A'`

**Working example.**

```js
$(function() {
  $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
      format: 'hh:mm A',
  });
  $('#datetimepicker2').datetimepicker({
      format: 'DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm A',
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.15.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.7.14/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.7.14/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class='col-sm-6'>
      <div class="form-group">
        <span>Select 12 hour time format</span>
        <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
          <input type='text' class="form-control" />
          <span class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
          </span>
        </div>
        <br/>
        <span>Select 12 hour time format with date</span>
        <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker2'>
          <input type='text' class="form-control" />
          <span class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48339355/6597375)

Answer (score 0):

in nowdays version, **2021 / 1 / Jan** you have to type in e.g.:

```
        $('#dateTimePicker').datetimepicker({
            .....,
            formatTime:'g:iA',
            format: 'Y.m.d hh:mm A',
            .....
        }
```

And you are done

Answer (score 0):

**Nothing worked** for me first because I was using the common '**bootstrap-datetimepicker**' that comes with bootstrap which is here :

http://www.malot.fr/bootstrap-datetimepicker (link is dead)

**BUT** the answers mentioned are for the plugin here:

https://demos.krajee.com/widget-details/datetimepicker

the lib that worked for me:

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.5.3/jquery.datetimepicker.css

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.5.3/build/jquery.datetimepicker.full.js

the JS code

```
$('.date-picker-2').datetimepicker({
    format: 'Y-m-d h:i a',
    todayHighlight: 'TRUE',
    autoClose: true,
    orientation: 'bottom right',
    step: 5
});
```

the output

```
2023-04-04 02:00 am
2023-04-04 07:45 pm
```