# Set dropdown with AM/PM options for time picker in PHP JQuery

Tags: php, jquery, datetimepicker, timepicker

I got a jquery plugin for a datetimepicker to be called in my PHP file. Everything works well, even until it getting integrated or posted into the database. However, I would like it to be in an AM/PM option, with the hours value starting at 1 and ending at 12. I have found a solution in a previous question here in the site, but what it only does is to convert the selected value (in 24-hour setting) into the equivalent time in AM/PM format. What I would prefer is that the dropdown of hours:minutes would be in hours:minutes AM/PM display, in a 12-hour setting.

The documentation for the jquery is at https://github.com/xdan/datetimepicker/blob/master/doc.tpl and a sample image of the time picker is at https://raw.githubusercontent.com/xdan/datetimepicker/master/screen/3.png. I have changed some values in the js files, such as loops reaching to 24 (assuming these are creating the values for hours 00-23) and made them 13 but to no effect. Thanks!

Comment: Could you make a jsfiddle or post some code?

Comment: More or less same with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22848383/how-to-set-am-pm-format-in-jquery-using-datetimepicker

Comment: $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
   datepicker:false,
   format:'g:i a',
   step:5
  });

Comment: perhaps using `dateFormat` on [line 377](https://github.com/xdan/datetimepicker/blob/master/doc.tpl) with `h:i a` as the format would work?

Comment: Hi @jraisanen. Yes, it does work somehow. But what it does is to simply convert my selected 24-hour-format time (like in a dropdown) to a 12-hour format into the text field. What I was hoping to have, though, is to have the actual dropdown options in the field in 12-hour format with AM/PM options. Here: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/xdan/datetimepicker/master/screen/3.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `format`, try using `formatTime` when initialising the datetime picker. The following should generate times in the 12h am/pm format in the drop-down,

```
jQuery('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
    datepicker: false,
    formatTime: 'h:i a'
});
```

Comment: This will show only Time in the specific format, but won't write in input field the same format...as @Lane pointed; you still need `format: 'h:i a'`

Answer (score 1):

Great help! Thanks! I'm posting my complete solution below. I retained the format item since having only formatTime would convert the dropdown list to 12-hour format, but when clicked would still post a 24-hour time format in the text field. Thanks!

```
    $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
        datepicker:false,
        formatTime:'h:i A',
        format: 'h:i A',
        step:5
    });
```