# Date and time format in bootstrap form

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I created simple form with date and time type inputs. It wants me to fill these fields with: `mm/dd/yyyy` and 12 hour AM/PM notation for time, but I'd like to have `dd/mm/yyyy` and 24 hour notation for time. How can I change it?

Here's the form: http://jsfiddle.net/s5un33n4/

Comment: Do you mind posting the form so we can see what you've tried? That would be most helpful!

Comment: It's in dd/mm/yyyy 24 hour system here. Probably has something to do with localisation and how my time is set in Windows. To force output like the way you want look for the solution below:)

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
    format: 'dd/mm/yyyy'
})
```

or as input element:

```
<input class="datepicker" data-date-format="dd/mm/yyyy">
```

according to the docs: https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/release/

for 24 hour system try this:

```
$(function () {
    $('#datetimepicker5').datetimepicker({
        use24hours: true
    });
});
```

[Using 24 hour time in bootstrap timepicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21021003/using-24-hour-time-in-bootstrap-timepicker)