# PHP convert date time

Tags: php

I have been trying around with the below time conversion and I'm not sure why it will give an empty result.

```
echo strtotime("2015/08/09 00:00 AM");
```

Comment: Remove the AM - the `00:00` is 24-hour and `strtotime()` doesn't recognise the AM as part of the timestamp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the "AM" - the `00:00` is 24-hour and `strtotime()` doesn't recognise the AM as part of the timestamp.

```
echo strtotime("2015/08/09 00:00 AM");
//outputs ""

echo strtotime("2015/08/09 00:00");
//outputs "1439103600"
```

Comment: is there any way if I wanted to convert from AM/PM ?

Comment: `08:00` is 8AM, `20:00` is 8PM. On 24-hour clock, you don't need to write AM/PM. If you want to change from AM to PM (or the reverse) you can add or remove 12 hours - to change `08:00` to `20:00` try `echo strtotime("2015/08/09 00:00 + 12 hours");`

Comment: the reason is because I'm using datetimepicker https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/ where it has AM/PM in it already.

Comment: @EricT To use 24 hours perhaps the answers on this question will help - http://stackoverflow.com/q/21021003/1241793