# Bootstrap3 datetime picker 24Hours option not working

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using bootstrap 3 datetime picker from the  link in
[eonasdan.github](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/)
but when I try to set an option for use24Hours I see a console error in line 1477 where key is the use24Hours?

```
 throw new TypeError('option ' + key + ' is not recognized!');
```

I am using version /*! version : 4.17.37 for bootstrap-datetimepicker.js

Here is how I am creating my datetime picker in javsacript.

```
("#mydiv").datetimepicker({ use24Hours: false });
```

I also tried small case for use24Hours as follows

```
("#mydiv").datetimepicker({ use24hours: false });
```

Based on the [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21021617/3038042)  that is the way to do it. What is wrong with mine?

Just as a note:
I can't use 
format:HH:mm because I that would change the whole datetime picker to just use the time format. but what I want is to keep the date format as of the current language I selected fr,us...etc but alter the time as I want regardless of the culture.

Comment: The answer you linked to is 2 years old. There's no `use24hours` option anymore, since the plug-in made the switch to using `Moment.JS`: http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/

Comment: So how can I change only the time format with out affecting anything else using the current?

Comment: try `{format: "H HH"}` http://momentjs.com/docs/

Comment: But that would get rid of the date I want to keep the date and change only the format of the time.

Answer (score 6):

For those still looking for an answer, just change the format to HH:mm

```
$("#id").datetimepicker({
    format: 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm'
});
```

*Note: I've also swapped the months and days around as that makes more sense to me*

Comment: I tried this, but I still have those AM and FM buttons in the picker.