# Disable or hide minutes in time_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I just want to disable or hide minutes in time_select in the rails form.
My motive is to prevent user to modify minutes, only he is allowed to modify hours not minutes.

```
<%= f.input :start_time, as: :time_select, hint: "Time is storing in UTC", include_blank: false %>
```

[image: As you can see in image]

Comment: There's no option for hiding minutes by using `time_select`, but you can use trick like css to hide that minute select or use normal input tag with integer type.

Comment: Then why not just have a number selection just for the hours? You don't need a time_select `<%= f.select :hours, options_for_select(1..24), { prompt: "Choose Hours" } %>`

Comment: Check out timepicker. It allows for setting formatting through javascript. https://github.com/tispratik/bootstrap-timepicker-rails and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21021003/using-24-hour-time-in-bootstrap-timepicker#answer-26786375

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done with jquery by inspecting minute field ID. :)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#property_promotion_start_time_5i').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
})
```

:) :)

Comment: Don't you forget to also check it on the server side? Since a user can easily modify it and remove the disabled part. There is also an [select_hour](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper/select_hour) tag.