# Javascript TimePicker 24 Hour Format

Tags: javascript, timepicker

On my website, I have a time picker, but I couldn't make it in 24-hour format.

Here is my HTML codes:

```
 <div class="input-group bootstrap-timepicker timepicker">
                                <asp:TextBox ID="weekday_opening" data-provide="timepicker" placeholder="Haftaiçi açılış" CssClass="form-control timepicker" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></span>
                            </div>
```

Here is my javascript code:

```
$(function () {
            $("#weekday_opening").timepicker({
                showInputs: false, //Set showInputs to false
            });
        })
```

I also tried to add

```
use24hours: true
showMeridian: false
```

[image]

Comment: That depends on your device settings, not on the website...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25874594/11068674
Use this it will work HH for 24 hours